# Sumar columna y agrupar por mes en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Necesito sumar todos los datos de ausentismo sin desagruparlos

Esta es mi consulta sql

```
  SELECT years, months,mes, ausentismo, empleados
      FROM (
          SELECT YEAR(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus) AS years, MONTH(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus) AS months,
               SUM(pa_ausentismo.horas_aus) AS ausentismo,
               COUNT(DISTINCT pa_ausentismo.id_empleados) AS empleados,
                     MonthName(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus) AS mes
          FROM pa_ausentismo
          WHERE DATE_FORMAT(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus, '%Y-%m-%d') = 2019 
          AND pa_ausentismo.status = 1
          GROUP BY YEAR(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus), MONTH(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus)
              ORDER BY YEAR(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus), MONTH(pa_ausentismo.fecha_aus)
      ) AS aus
```

Este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La mejor opcion es agregar una nueva columna para mostrar el resultado de la suma total de "ausentismo" pero no encuentro la manera de realizarlo

Comment: Cual es el resultado que esperas obtener viendo el ejemplo que nos pones? Tal y como esta la pregunta no entiendo que es lo que buscas.

Comment: No entiendo lo que querés lograr, ¿querés filas con la suma total de ausentismo?

Comment: necesito sumar la columna ausentismo, pero sin desagruparlos, porque si le quito  group by ya la suma!, espero me pudas ayudar